# Is ant media mobile SDK support to share native mobile scree?

Tags: android, ios, sdk

Is ant media mobile SDK support to share native mobile scree? If yes it would be much appreciated if some example would be available because everywhere I can see camera broadcasting not the native screen sharing for mobile devices.